# CSS - lost grid remove lost-column, media query

Tags: css, postcss

I have a codepen here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PyegKY

I have a simple grid using lost grid.

At smaller screen sizes is it possible to stop the lost grid.

I can make the divs 100% but I want a more complicated layout on smaller screens where div one and two are on the same line and the others are below.

I'm also having issues with the lost grid margins so it would be easier to stop the lost grid at smaller screen sizes.

```
@use lost;

.block{
  max-width: 900px;
}

.item{
  background: lightgrey;
  lost-column: 1/5;
}

@media(max-width: 500px){
  .item{
    lost-column: 1;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `min-width` and second argument of `lost-column` to the `.item` so:

```
.item{
  background: lightgrey;
  min-width: 35%;
  lost-column: 1/5 2;
}
```

example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YJLbxw

Comment: Hi, I wanted the divs to be on one line and then on smaller screens have them be 100% width apart from the first two divs

Comment: then it would be easier in js.